# Escape HTML Value meaning?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a `{{expression}}`. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", `{{{`

What does it mean to HTML-escape a value?

Comment: It will be shown in your html page as if you used the `<pre>code</pre>` attribute.

Comment: look at their documentation http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping, it explains with an example for both the scenarios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The following characters are reserved in HTML and must be replaced with their corresponding HTML entities: ~[(Online HTML Formatter)](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html)

- `"` is replaced with `&quot;`
- `&` is replaced with `&amp;`
- `<` is replaced with `&lt;`
- `>` is replaced with `&gt;`

Examples say more than a thousand words:

```js
var source   = $("#template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 

var data = {
  escaped   : '{{}}',
  notescaped: '{{{}}}',
  html      : "<a href='https://google.com/'>Google <strong>Search</strong></a>",
}

$('body').append(template(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

<h4>Escaped HTML double curly brackets: <code>{{escaped}}</code></h4>
{{html}}
<p>It's just non interactive string</p>

<hr>

<h4>Not escaped HTML tripple curly brackets: <code>{{notescaped}}</code></h4>
{{{html}}}

<p>It basically ends up as parsed HTML</p>




</script>
```

And then, [handlebarsjs.com](http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping) on the matter is a good read, too.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a string like `<br>` in your expression, using two brackets (`{{ expression }}`) would convert that `<br>` into an HTML break element.

But if you use three brackets (`{{{ expression }}}`), then the `<br>` would print how it appears and would not be converted into an HTML element.

Comment: It's actually the other way around: `{{ expression }}` escapes the value, while `{{{ expression }}}` does not.

Answer (score 2):

From their documentation:

If you look at the `h1` tag, the `<p>` tag is escaped and so its displayed as `&lt;p&gt`;

If you look at the `body` tag, because of `{{{}}}`  the string is displayed however it is. the first `<p>` tag and last `</p>` closing tags are not escaped.

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{{body}}}
  </div>
</div>
```

and the values of title and body are as follows

```
{
  title: "All about <p> Tags",
  body: "<p>This is a post about &lt;p&gt; tags</p>"
}
```

The resulting is:

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>All About &lt;p&gt; Tags</h1>
  <div class="body">
    <p>This is a post about &lt;p&gt; tags</p>
  </div>
</div>
```